# Error to build native library from Android studio 6.1

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio

**Category:** Using NDK with Android studio on Windows 7 64-bit

MyProject has MyNdkProject native code under MyNDKProject/src/main/jni/ path.
.so file gets generated using ndk-build.cmd from Android Studio terminal.

However, when executing the complete project it exits with following error from gradle console

> '"D:\MyProjectPath\find-win-host.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':MyNdkProject:ndkBuild'.
>
> > Process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

How to resolve this problem with Android studio?

Comment: You have to mention what operating system you are using.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Windows 7 professional 64-bit Operating system

Comment: If your project full path contains spaces, e.g. `c:\My Projects`, you can have lots of troubles with NDK build.

Comment: Thank you @AlexCohn, we are having trouble with Android Studio, however the native build gets executed from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is resolved with Android Studio Beta (0.8.4) and gradle version (1.12) 
java version is 7v67, older java version was 7v25.

It seems that problem was due to older java version. Please agree.