# Android ndk aborting... stop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am facing the following error in android studio but this app works perfect in eclipse. Help me solve this problem .[image]

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 @cafebabe1991

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504149/error-to-build-native-library-from-android-studio-6-1.